# jquery function is not working

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

i m currently reading jquery and i m facing some issues on jquery functions.. can any one guide me regarding functions . currently i want to create only one function and call twice a time if req is same .. but function is not working pls experts guide me in the code .

```
var errorAlpha = function(){

        $(this).focus().keyup(function(){

            var reg = /^([A-Za-z]+)$/;
            var check = $(this).val();              

            if(reg.test(check)==true && check.match(reg)==true)
              {
                    $(this).removeClass('error_Aplha');
              }
              else {
                    $(this).addClass('error_Aplha');
              }

            }),blur(function(){

                var check = $(this).val();
                var reg = /^([A-Za-z]+)$/;

                if(reg.test(check)==true && check.match(reg)==true)
                  {
                    $(this).removeClass('error_Aplha');
                  }
                else {
                    $(this).addClass('error_Aplha');
                  } 

            });


    };

        $('#step1 #fName').function(errorAlpha());
```

Html Is here

```
<input type="text" class="width-260" id="fName"/>
```

Css is here

```
.error_Aplha {
border:1px solid #b20000 !important;    

box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #b20000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #b20000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #b20000;
 }
```

Comment: You have a syntax error `}),blur`. Debugging your code is _the very first_ step towards finding an error. Indenting your code properly also helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code `$('#step1 #fName').function(errorAlpha());` is wrong. Nothing is going to happen.

If you want to trigger something then you need to attach a event handlers like click, key, mouse events. Here is the one way to set event handler,

```
 $('#step1 #fName').keypress(function(){
   errorAlpha();
 });
```

Here is the list of jQuery event methods, http://api.jquery.com/category/Events/

**Update:**

I updated your code and it's working here http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/gU3PU/2/

Comment: pls check this link want to tag validation on one function but still not work
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/X3ZDQ/6/)

Comment: @GreatOne what are you validating?

Comment: only checking alpha .. if aplha values enter then values correct.. other wise if they enter any values except alpha errors show

Comment: @GreatOne Sounds like a another problem not related to your question.  Please post this issue has a new question and someone help help you.

Comment: but before this function validation is working i think some thing wrong in this function

Comment: Ok, then check here, http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/gU3PU/2/ let me know if this works.

Comment: some thing wrong still but thank @Muthu Kumaran you r very help to me .. but Guffa solve this issue link is here http://jsfiddle.net/y4UtT/

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error here:

```
}),blur(function(){
```

You should use a period:

```
}).blur(function(){
```

When you try to use the function, you are using a method that doesn't exists, and you have parentheses after the function name with means that the function is called when you bind the event, not when the event happens.

This:

```
$('#step1 #fName').function(errorAlpha());
```

should be something like:

```
$('#step1 #fName').click(errorAlpha);
```

The `match` method doesn't return a boolean, it returns an array or `null`:

```
if (reg.test(check) == true && check.match(reg) != null) {
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/y4UtT/

Comment: both i was using method
   '}),blur(function(){'
or
   '}).blur(function(){'
but both still not working pls explain more

Comment: @GreatOne: I tested the code, and the remaining problem is with the `match` method. See the edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Create the function separately which you want to use twice.

```
function common(){
...
}
```

Then you can do

```
$(' #fName').focus().blur(common);

$(' #fName').blur(common);
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
function errorAlpha(obj){
    var reg = /^([A-Za-z]+)$/;
    var check = $(obj).val();              

    if(reg.test(check)==true && check.match(reg)==true)
    {
        $(obj).removeClass('error_Aplha');
   }
    else {
        $(obj).addClass('error_Aplha');
   }

 }
 $('#fName').focus().keyup(function(){
        errorAlpha(this);
     }).blur(function(){
            errorAlpha(this);
  });
```